# Iterating the json response

Tags: javascript

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/VEB0PT7yZO1yuOxtrXGP/

**I tried the following way, but i could not get the result.**

```
     for (i = 0, len = json.PatientListGetResult.Appointments.length; i < len && i <= 100; i++) {
          alert(json.PatientListGetResult.Appointments[i].Patient.PatientID);
      }
```

How can i iterate this response, so that i can get the each Patient's Name and ID. There are total 11 rows.

Comment: you can start by pasting a fragment of the response in your post.

Comment: Always post all of the relevant code/markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question It's okay if it's long, just put it at the end so your question doesn't get lost. (And **wow**, at least from my connection, that paste site is *slow* [and in fact, times out or fails periodically].)

Answer (score 1):

working here: http://jsfiddle.net/UsvFV/

In the json response, you had missed out '}' (the last right curly bracket)

Comment: Always put the relevant code/markup **in the answer itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: I have just added his own code in JSFiddle with just a small addition from me: '}' :)